# After using the format shortcut, the keyboard is locked in idea2019, is this a bug in this version?

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

My company supply IDEA2019 for coding. I found a bug is that  after using the format shortcut,e.g. Ctrl+Shift+F, a notification is showed and the keyboard is locked. First i think it is the notification result in the lock. However, after cancelling the notification, the lock is still. I must move the mouse, but don't need knock, then the keyboard is unlocked and I can continue to input words. Is this a bug in the Idea2019?

what i do have showed in the above details.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem in build 2019.3.5 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html . Try to temporarily disable [all third-party plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) and restart the IDE

Comment: If the problem remains, backup and delete/move [all IDE directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and reinstall the IDE from scratch. Contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for further assistance

Comment: @EgorKlepikov thank you very much. After following the steps you said, the problem has been solved. Now I think may be the problem of the IdeaVim plugin. MayBe. Never mind, the prolblem has been solved. Thank you again.